# Complex joins with legacy tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm writing fairly simple web interface for invoice/customer/contract database.
I would like to have the following structure for my models:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_table_name 't10_invoices'
   set_primary_key 'id_invoice'
   has_one :client
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_table_name 't20_clients'
   set_primary_key 'id_client'
   has_many :invoices
end
```

The problem is that I have the following database structure:

```
Tables:
t10_invoices:
   id_invoice - primary_key
   id_contract - foreign_key


t12_contracts:
   id_contract - primary_key      

t15_contracts_clients
   id_client - foreign_key
   id_contract - foreign_key

t20_clients
   id_client - primary_key
```

There is 1-1 relation between `t20_clients` and `t12_contracts` through `t15_contracts_clients`
and there is 1-n relation between `t20_clients` and `t10_invoices`.

What is the difference between `:foreign_key` and `:association_foreign_key`?

The problem is that I cannot modify the structure of the database and I'm quite lost in the redefining the table names, foreign keys, join_foreign_keys etc... 
I would like a simple way to find clients of invoice in normal Rails way `Invoice.find(:first).client`

I would appreciate any suggestions and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `ContractClient` Join Model to correspond to the t15_contracts_clients table. This specifies the table name and uses `belongs_to` associations for the 2 foreign keys:

```
class ContractClient < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 't15_contracts_clients'
  belongs_to :client, :foreign_key => :id_client
  belongs_to :contract, :foreign_key => :id_contract
end
```

Specify the table and primary key for `Client`:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 't20_clients'
  set_primary_key 'id_client'
end
```

Use a `belongs_to :contract_client` on Invoice and then a `has_one :through` to associate the client through the `ContractClient`:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 't10_invoices'
  set_primary_key 'id_invoice'
  belongs_to :contract_client, :foreign_key => :id_contract
  has_one :client, :through => :contract_client
end
```

`Invoice.find(:first).client` should then behave as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of oddities in the model. It is not set up in such a way that client `has_one` contract. It has a join table in the middle which allows for multiple contracts per client. Since you can't change the tables, it's best to just enforce whatever relationships there are in code. Since that table apparently does not have a primary key, you probably need to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`.  In that relationship type, `:association_foreign_key` is for the "other" class, and `:foreign_key` is for the class you are in.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_table_name 't10_invoices'
   set_primary_key 'id_invoice'
   belongs_to :contract, :foreign_key => 'id_contract'
   has_one :client, :through => :contract
end

class Contract
  set_table_name 't12_contracts'
  set_primary_key 'id_contract'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients, 
                           :join_table => 't15_contracts_clients' 
                           :foreign_key => 'id_contract',
                           :association_foreign_key => 'id_client'
  has_many :invoices, :foreign_key => 'id_contract'
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_table_name 't20_clients'
   set_primary_key 'id_client'
   has_and_belongs_to_many :clients, 
                           :join_table => 't15_contracts_clients' 
                           :foreign_key => 'id_client',
                           :association_foreign_key => 'id_contract'
   has_many :invoices, :through => :contracts
end
```

You then need to invoke

```
Invoice.find(:first).client
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a database [view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database))?

Comment: Yes,I was thinking about creating Views but i would prefer to do it all in rails - so it will be much more flexible instead of having ask the DBA to create views.

Comment: I see. In my team, we're maintaining database as well, so I always prefer to iron out database inconsistencies using views and keep my app logic clean as possible. Useful also if you ever get a chance to rewrite DB schema properly.
However, views usually not editable, so one should keep that in mind.